# Reshaping large pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to reshape the dataframe that is shown below. There are roads that have several coordination and location points. I would like to have one single row per road with all the data points after each other. You can find the desired output in the dataframe below this one. Keeping the indices is not important.

If you know how to fix this, would be great!

```
index   road          lrp      lat                 lon
1346    N1           LRP467    20.862972        92.298083
1347    N1           LRPE      20.862917        92.298083
1348    N101         LRPS      23.454139        91.212861
1349    N101         LRPSa     23.461889        91.212000
```

The desired output:

```
index   road          lrp1     lat1         lon1        lrp2  lat2          lon2
1346    N1           LRP467    20.862972    92.298083   LRPE  20.862917     92.298083
1348    N101         LRPS      23.454139    91.212861  LRPSa  23.461889     91.212000
```

My actual dataframe is way larger than this example (more than 10000 records), so if you know a solution that could be applied to a larger dataframe, would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `index` is an index not a column:

```
m= df.groupby(['road']).cumcount() + 1
df = df.set_index(['road', m]).unstack().sort_index(1, level=1)
df.columns = ['_'.join(map(str,i)) for i in df.columns]
print(df.reset_index())

   road      lat_1      lon_1   lrp_1      lat_2      lon_2  lrp_2
0    N1  20.862972  92.298083  LRP467  20.862917  92.298083   LRPE
1  N101  23.454139  91.212861    LRPS  23.461889  91.212000  LRPSa
```